# Ubuntu using i5 integrated card instead of R7

Tags: drivers, 16.04, graphics, radeon, integrated

I have the following `lspci -nn`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 0b)
...
09:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360] [1002:6900] (rev ff)
```

How can I make sure to use the R7 with **radeon** drivers on 16.04?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected, given it's a hybrid solution. One has to use `DRI_PPRIME=1 <command>` to use it.